# Added second network adapter and can't get a connection from ether

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I have since dropped the second Ethernet adapter totally. I still couldn't get it to work so I reinstalled ubuntu (was working with a fresh install anyway) The adapter worked fine to begin. Then I tried to set the static settings in the interfaces file. It broke again. I could not start networking. reverted to the original settings, still nothing. The only other change I have made when all this started was enabling the onboard ethernet. But thats not showing up in the hardware at all. I am going to try disabling that and if that dosent work then go back to 12.10.

---

I am trying to bridge two ethernet adapters on my server. I have a second long range wireless AP that I want to network through the server.

I tried adding br0 with all the proper settings on the interfaces file but that just broke the ethernet connection. I commented it out and went back to my normal setup.

Now the interfaces are down on boot. and when I manually put them up they go up but do not connect or use the static info in the interfaces file.

I am happy to get more info that would be helpful.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
     address 192.168.2.9
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.2.1
     network 192.168.2.0
     broadcast 192.168.2.255

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.2.3
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.2.1
     network 192.168.2.0
     broadcast 192.168.2.255

#auto br0
#iface br0 inet static
     #address 192.168.2.9
     #netmask 255.255.255.0
     #gateway 192.168.2.1
     #network 192.168.2.0
     #broadcast 192.168.2.255
     #bridge_ports eth1 eth0
     #bridge_fd 9
     #bridge_hello 2
     #bridge_maxage 12
     #bridge_stp off
```

Also when I run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` I get `start: job failed to start`

Comment: You put eth0 and eth1 on the same network, which is unconventional. And you use same gateway on them. You only need to set up one gateway in one of the interfaces. You should tell us the output of 'ip addr' and 'ip route'. I would also try to only set up one of the ports in each network. I would set up the other as a router between the nets. And unless you have a really strange net, never set network and broadcast. Linux calculate that from address and netmask.

Comment: as I stated, I got rid of eth1 (physically removed) and reinstalled ubuntu from scratch. It worked until I tried to set a static IP. then I could not start networking. I tried going back to the original file and still could not get networking to start. I think this may be a ubuntu 13.04 bug. I am currently trying to go back to 12.10 which is what I was using originaly. and I gave up on the idea if bridging. I just need to static ip.

Answer (score 0):

I think you the best solution for you is building a router using IPTABLES, the most stable and safe solution should be using NAT (MASQUERADE)
A good tutorial can be found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=111972

Answer (score 0):

I installed a second network card on the server and start apt-get update;upgrade  but the server could not connect to internet .The first thing I thought is card is DOA or broken but ifconfig  and ifconfig eth1 up make my day.

http://bemonolit.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/how-to-start-second-network-adapter.html